# How to update React native dependencies

Tags: react-native

I created a project via Expo with version 22.0.0. Now i want to update the dependency from package.json. Can anybody help me what would be the efficient way to update the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Interactive CLI utility to easily update outdated NPM dependencies with changelogs inspection support.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade

execute:

```
npm upgrade
```

Comment: Or `npm upgrade --force`